# Rest client to change wordpress content

Tags: wordpress, rest, web-services, wordpress-rest-api

I decided to start with website development and I started reading things on google and I ended up on the wordpress. I got inspired the way wordpress works and I ended on the YouTube video by Tyler Moorey link: https://youtu.be/2cbvZf1jIJM and successfully created good looking website in a day. Many thanks to Tyler.

Now I have to change contents of my website like gallery, video, some text etc from admin panel(not wordpress admin panel). I have created rest API in php which is able to upload contents to database from postman. Now the main part where I am confused is
1. I needs to have some client application which is able to communicate with REST api like postman. 
2. I am planning to have a web page with admin login instead of having a native application. Using this user will login and update the contents of my WordPress website.

I searched so many things regarding REST api with wordpress but still I don't find answers to my question, how my admin web page will communicate to wordpress website to update content using rest api?

Is it a good practice to create admin web page over Window's desktop app or any other native app? If yes then how to create admin web page so as to communicate with WordPress? Or else just add the login functionality to WordPress website and land user to another page instead of website.